# Test for infinite series convergence or divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi what would be a good test to find convergence or divergence please?

$\sum _1 ^{\infty} (e^kcos^2k)/ \pi ^k$

My attempt I got that converges thanks

Comment: It looks possible since the terms go to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity.  What tests are you familiar with?

Comment: The partial sum is increasing and bounded, hence it converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$0\le \cos^2(\hbox{anything})\le1$$
we have
$$0\le\frac{e^k\cos^2k}{\pi^k}\le\frac{e^k}{\pi^k}=\Bigl(\frac{e}{\pi}\Bigr)^k\ .$$
And
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bigl(\frac{e}{\pi}\Bigr)^k$$
converges since it is a GP with ratio $e/\pi<1$, so your series converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$I=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{k}\cos^{2}(k)}{\pi^{k}}$$ $$J=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{k}\sin^{2}(k)}{\pi^{k}}$$ So $$I+J=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{k}}{\pi^{k}}=\frac{e}{\pi-e }$$ which is a geometric series.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

It converges absolutly due to the estimate
$$|\cos^{2}(n)|\leq 1$$